# How do I create an app to customize notification panel for Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-notifications, android-quick-settings

I want to customize notification panel in my device. Specifically, I want to move quick tiles to bottom of the panel instead of top as it is easily accessible there. But if search Google for 'Android development - Notifications panel', it shows results to customize my apps notifications instead of customizing the notification panel. I don't know where to start. Can someone help me by pointing out resources regarding this?

Comment: I found quick settings `Tile` class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  That's part of the system UI, and there's no API to reconfigure it like that.

Only a custom system image (that is, a modified version of the Android operating system) with a modified version of the system UI could do this.

While you can supply your own notifications, quick settings tiles, etc., they still can only be shown in the normal locations.

Comment: Hey @Ryan. Thanks. But I have seen apps like Power Shade that allow you to customise your notification shade.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB They're using an `AccessbilityService` to detect when the top of the screen is touched and bring in their own notification shade, which they've likely recreated entirely within their app using the AOSP source.  I wouldn't really recommend that...it's going to be pretty fragile, for one, and it won't detect alternative ways of opening the notification shade.  You'll also have to reimplement quite a lot of the notification shade functionality.